# How to replace string with blank in pandas data frame column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have pandas data frame column, I want to replace Hyperparameters column string with blanks '  '.

I tried below command to replace with blank but does not work, please let me know how to replace with blank?

new_df = df.Hyperparameters.str.replace('{'max_samples': 20, 'contamination':', ' ')

df:

```
Accuracy    Hyperparameters 
0.902475    {'max_samples': 20, 'contamination': 0.1647368...
0.488819    {'max_samples': 100, 'contamination': 0.697719...
0.834296    {'max_samples': 70, 'contamination': 0.2875438...
0.608662    {'max_samples': 80, 'contamination': 0.5749122...
0.505224    {'max_samples': 10, 'contamination': 0.6731578...
0.792928    {'max_samples': 80, 'contamination': 0.3415789...
```

Convert into:

new_df:

```
Accuracy    Hyperparameters 
0.902475    0.1647368...
0.488819    0.697719...
0.834296    0.2875438...
0.608662    0.5749122...
0.505224    0.6731578...
0.792928    0.3415789...
```

Comment: List comprehension on `Hyperparameters` and get value where `key==contamination` ?

Comment: Are you certain that `Hyperparameters` are strings, and not dicts?  Try `print(type(df.Hyperparameters.iloc[0]))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `df.apply`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Accuracy": [0.902475, 0.488819], "Hyperparameters": [{'max_samples': 20, 'contamination': 0.1647368}, {'max_samples': 100, 'contamination': 0.697719}]})
df["Hyperparameters"] = df["Hyperparameters"].apply(lambda x: x["contamination"])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Accuracy  Hyperparameters
0  0.902475         0.164737
1  0.488819         0.697719
```

- You have a dictionary in the `Hyperparameters` column

Comment: Note that if your DataFrame is very large, `apply()` will be much slower than a vectorized approach.